# how to send more than ten messages via Twilio

Tags: twilio

I currently have developed a REST API that Twilio posts when an incoming message comes to a short code. Sometimes the reply message can have more than 10 sms messages and it looks like Twilio has a limit for the reply message as I see error in the Notification logs mentioning that it cannot send more than 10 messages. So what is the best way to get through this error? 
Should I call the Twilio API for sending out the messages instead of using the Twilio Response? If so what should my HTTP response be? Little confused on what response should I be sending for the HTTP Response. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just send nothing as the response, but use the opportunity to send out the 10+ messages using the [twilio api](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest).

Alternatively, send the first messages as the response and that send the 9+ immediately after as a new conversation.

Comment: I am trying to send nothing as the response but I have attached a  TwiML bin URL attached to my short code as a Message Fall Back URL in case Twilio is not able to connect to my REST API. So now when a Text message is received and the response is sent then I am getting the response from the Message FallBack URL as well as the actual response for my text message. Is there anyway to fix this? Please help.